# Latex Table - Column form

Tags: tables

When I put the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Air & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textit{Oscilations/180s}} \\
\hline
521&521&522\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I obtain this:

[image]

But I would like that the second row, second and third columns, have the same size.

Can anyone help me?

Just another doubt, how can I add a piece of Latex Code in a more estilista way?

Thanks.

Comment: for the end of row use  "\\" not just "\"

Answer (score 2):

- for the second and third column you had to prescribe the same column width to both, i.e. you should use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}{p{<column width>}` instead `c` column type. the sume of both column width had to be larger than width of `multicolumn` which span this two columns.
- centering of `p{...}` column contents you need to load the package `array`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{12mm}|}}
\hline
Air & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{Oscilations/180s}} \\
\hline
521&521&522\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- for better code formatting in question you should move code for four spaces to right. this you also can do with help of `{}` in tool rows above this window.